# IBM Worklight - dojo script.js:21 error while deploying dojo application

Tags: android, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I created my first app to show some HTML on IBM worklight. Here's what i did:

1. created a new project added navigation , dojo views and some such stuff
2. deployed it , previewed it
3. working fine in console as well as mobile browser simulator but not in avd or device
4. googled about this error, the only clear info i got was to uncheck the dojo library requests option from the console

   i did that and the before and after results are provided in case you want to see them.

The only error i got in logcat(red colored flags: not sure if errors or warning as some people on google said they can be ignored but still here they are)

> ```
> 08-16 17:14:52.306: E/Web Console(586): Error: scriptError at file:///data/data/com.htmlProj/files/www/default/dojo/dojo.js:21
> 08-16 17:14:52.327: E/Web Console(586): Error: scriptError at file:///data/data/com.htmlProj/files/www/default/dojo/dojo.js:21
> ```

Here are the snapshots of console, MBS, and device before unchecking the Dojo Library requests:

[image: MBS result with dojo library requests]
[image: Console result]
[image: device (galaxy grand)]

And here are the screenshots after unchecking the Provide Library Requests:
[image: device view]

The MBS and the console look the same. You can see that the device and the AVD show something  yet they don't navigate to different pages, don't show the bottom toolbar.

---

here is the project structure , i think i have the *root.js files too

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A quick search in Stackoverflow will bring up these questions on the same topic, as well as a fix: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bworklight%5D%5Bdojo%5D+is%3Aquestion+scripterror%3A21

Comment: I tried that post and did not get the solution dats why posting it again, i even posted a query there also sometime back but no replies

Comment: The solution suggest to also add the root.js files. Did you? You do not specify this in your question.

Comment: yeah sorry forgot to mention that, but they are already there in my project

Comment: What is your Worklight version? Where did you place the files? Which files did you place?

Comment: its 6.0 and i placed those *.js files in my assets/www/default/dojo/nls folder and i have updated my question with the project structure

Comment: okay i see in the dojo library requests console, it is something like this - [2013-08-17 14:08:07] Application 'WLDoc' requested a missing resource. Providing library resource:
 /WLDoc/toolkit/dojo/dojox/mobile/sniff.js and many more files like this so i copied the whole toolkit folder from my dojo library folder in WLdoc, is this i am supposed to do or copy those resources anywhere else....

Answer (score 0):

I have been suffering the same problem... I have followed every step that have been described in this forum and they didn't work...Finally, I realized that my application was asking for mobile-ui-layer-es.js and core-web-layer-es.js, so check if you are adding to www/dojo/nls the libraries that your project needs depending on the language.